# What is the practical difference between a static function and a function with the "hidden" visibility attribute?

Tags: c, visibility

I know that using the `static` keyword in C on a function restricts the function to the compilation unit in which it is defined. I am now looking into symbol visibility, and I'm a little confused about the difference between `static` functions and function marked with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`, or using the `-fvisibility=hidden` command-line option.

I have a feeling that the way these change things under-the-hood is not at all the same, but I don't know what the difference is nor what it implies when working with them in actual code. What changes between the two, and when would you want to use one over the other?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A function with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` is not visible outside the shared library containing it, but if that library was made by linking `foo.pic.o` and `bar.pic.o` such a function `fhid` can be defined in `foo.c` and called from `bar.c`. Of course outside code (e.g. from the main program or some other shared library) cannot call that `fhid`

So hidden visibility applies to an entire shared library, not to individual compilation units composing it.

In contrast, it would have been possible for `foo.c` to define a `static void fsta(void)` function, and for `bar.c` to define a *different* `static void fsta(void)` function (even if that is poor taste and should be avoided for readability reasons).

Also, in principle, a `static` function could be more easily inlined, or the compiler could (sometimes) use different calling conventions for it.

Comment: but not from outside the DLL +1

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `global` function in a shared library you'd want to be used only within the context of the shared library, but not outside the shared library - then you need `__attribute__((visiblity("hidden")))`

For example:

If you have a function `void foo()` defined in `Foo.c` and you'd want it to refer from `Bar.c` and `Baz.c` which are compilation units to produce `FooBarBaz.dll`(or FooBarBaz.so) then you can make the function as

```
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) void foo() {}
```

Remember, `foo()` will not be visible to the executable that loads the `dll`(or the .so file)
Read this [paper](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

> Hidden visibility indicates that the symbol will not be
>             placed into the dynamic symbol table, so no other "module"
>             (executable or shared library) can reference it directly.

http://ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html

I can add: You can use `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` in C++ with semantics close to C's version of `static`.

Comment: Not exactly: you can have two different `static` functions of the same name `f` in two different compilation units. You cannot have 2 such functions `f` with hidden visibility